# Oauth to allow common log-in to two websites that I own

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, security, oauth

I have two ASP.NET websites, call them Older.com (using ancient ASP.NET WebPages) and Newer.com (which is a combination of WebPages and MVC), with separate login systems. I would like to allow the user of Older.com to be able to link their accounts to an existing Newer.com account, or create an account with Newer.com, and I think I want to do it using OAuth.

As I understand it, OAuth is generally used to allow users to login to a site using an existing account with the likes of Facebook, Google, Microsoft, etc.. However, I might not want to use Google/FB/MSoft accounts to create an OAuth token, but instead use an Older.com password to generate token that also grants them Newer.com access.

Basically, would it make sense to do this using OAuth? Do I have to use a link to an established provider Goog/FB/MSoft to use OAuth? And, are there security issues I should be concerned about when using OAuth?

Any advice, help, experience, or references are appreciated!

edit:

The reason for this is that resources that used to be hosted on Older.com are being moved to Newer.com, because Older.com needs to be rebuilt and the Newer.com is designed around storing and linking related resources. You could think of Newer.com as a place where you can keep an article, but you can also keep all the things related to that article (images, primary sources, derived works), whereas Older.com would just store a copy of the articles with no associated information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wtyneb,

So there are a couple of ways to approach the problem you've encountered. There are many popular solutions to this problem, but two of them are: `OAuth` and `OpenID`. OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server. On the other hand, `OpenID` eliminates the need for webmasters to provide their own ad hoc systems and allowing users to consolidate their digital identities. In other words, users can log into multiple unrelated websites without having to register with their information over and over again.

The main difference between `OAuth` and `OpenID` is that OpenID is about authentication (ie. proving who you are), OAuth is about authorisation (ie. to grant access to functionality/data/etc.. without having to deal with the original authentication).

OAuth could be used in external partner sites to allow access to protected data without them having to re-authenticate a user.

In your case, if your users to Newer.com aren't  using any information from Older.com, then it makes more of a sense to use an OpenID approach. Implementing OAuth would be over-engineering the solution in this case.

You can provide the credentials by either [integrating OpenID](http://openid.net/) into both your Older.com and Newer.com websites, or simply build out the same type of infrastructure into your back end. You can do that by simply exposing a REST API (which you might already be having to authenticate) in your Older.com website. What this does is simply verify the login credentials you have in Older.com when people log into your Newer.com, Newest.com, or any other website you might create in the future.

Please let me know if you have any questions!